# Filtering Data by Date Using Sql Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i want to filtering data from MySql database by date to datagrid..

i tried this code but in datagrid doesnt return anything or empty..

```
"SELECT x1, x2, x3, xdate  FROM data WHERE xdate='" & LblDate.Text.ToString & "'"
```

but if i change filter to x1 or x2 or x3 it work as well...

xdate column is date with format d/M/yyyy..

and i tried this code to but i got error about my sql version..

```
"SELECT x1, x2, x3, xdate  FROM data WHERE xdate CONVERT(VARCHAR(10, xdate, 110))='" & LblDate.Text.ToString & "'"
```

the error..

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.25a]You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'CONVERT(VARCHAR(10, xdate, 110))='3/4/2014'' at line 1

pls help..thanks.

Comment: Why not use bind variables?

Comment: umm... i never use bind variables, can u show me to use that method?

Comment: look into parameterized query. With that, you can pass `DateTime` object to the query without bother converting it to string with valid format according to MySQL culture, moreover parameterized query save you from SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
"SELECT x1, x2, x3, xdate  FROM data 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(xdate,'%d/%m/%Y')='" & LblDate.Text.ToString & "'
```

Comment: wow.. i dont know how but it work... i just change '%d/%m/%Y' to '%d/%m/%yyyy'.. thanks.